# Generate new token on page refresh in PHP

Tags: php, token

I want to create a token based Web API in PHP so as to achieve the following;

1. A new token should be generated after successful login on the `Login_api.php` page.
2. After authenticating a user in the scenario above, another token should be generated and sent with search query results for all queries submitted on the page at `search_api.php`.
3. Also, in order to get an information from the page at `get_Details_api.php`, the user will send the above regenerated token to authenticate to this API.

Like this every time new token need to be generated to authenticate user, so how should I implement that?

What approach should I use?

How do I validate this new token?

Where should I store this token?

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to this community! We would be happy to help you fix your existing code, but we are not here to write code for you. 
Please read [help/how-to-ask].

(and why reïnvent the wheel. Use a framework with api and authentication support like Symfony)

Comment: ok i will do that @Daan